# Voltage gain of BJT CE stage amplifier

Tags: transistors, amplifier, bjt

[image]

The question is to calculate the voltage gain, V_out / V_in in terms of small signal parameters and R_C.
(Ignore Early effect)

First I made a small signal circuit for it, and found voltage gain. But it's different from the solution... I can't found any wrong step from my calculation. What's the problem?

Comment: Looks good to me, I didn't notice a mistake. The solution also looks suspicious. How would Rc and Rpi2 be in parallel? Possibly somebody else can check again.